# How to receive all data properly via TCP/IP C#

Tags: c#, tcp, system.net.sockets

Please forgive me for a silly question but I'm really can't find a solution.
This is this way I'm trying to do it:

```
public void FillBuf(object sender)
{
    var handler = (Socket)sender;

    while (true)
    {
        received = 0;

        while (received < 1024)
        {
        int block = handler.Receive(bytes, received, bytes.Length - received, SocketFlags.None);
        received += block;
        }

        que.Enqueue(bytes);
    }
```

At the beginning of the program I start thread which executes `FillBuf` method. The problem is that I never receive 1024 bytes for some reason. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that on the other end of the socket, the server is actually sending 1024 bytes?

Comment: how many bytes are you receiving ?

Comment: At the client I'm receiving 463 bytes. The server also has 1024 bytes buffer to send but It could be not always full. Probably this is the problem?

Comment: If the server sends less than the expected number of bytes, your client code will block until it gets the expected amount. Normally you should have something on the top of TCP that indicates how many bytes are going to be sent, so that the client knows how much to expect and read. Take for example the `Content-Length` header in the HTTP protocol. Do you have such mechanism in your protocol?

Comment: It's hard to tell if the problem is in your client without seeing the server code. But nevertheless your code will block forever in the case it receives LESS than 1024 bytes.

Comment: So if I'm sending an array of bytes with size of 1024 and some of those bytes at the end of the array are equal to zero, client won't recognize it as data?

Comment: It doesn't matter the value of the bytes at all. It's their number. When you call the Receive method on the client you indicate how many bytes you want to read. If the server doesn't send that much bytes, the client code will hang.

Comment: Now I see, It's not always send 1024 bytes from a server indeed. It seems I understood my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the server isn't always sending 1024 bytes. This means that the client code which is expecting them will hang until it gets the correct amount of data. You should make sure that the server is sending the expected number of bytes or implement some mechanism in your protocol that would allow the sender to indicate at the beginning of the payload the number of bytes it is going to send. This way the client will know how many bytes to read.